# phonegap / cordova module not found

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, bluetooth

I installed a plugin and in its plugin.xml

```
<js-module src="www/org.bcsphere/bc.js" name="bcjs">
    <merges target="BC" />
</js-module>
```

Do I have to still add the js file to my app's index.html?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="org.bcsphere/bc.js"></script>
```

In the **myapp/plugins/org.bcsphere.bluetooth/www/org.bcsphere/org.bcsphere/bc.js** file

```
    var root = this;
    /**
     * BC namespace includes all kinds of magic things, all the classes is registered on it, enjoy it :).
     * @property {string} VERSION - The version of BC
     * @namespace
     */
    var BC;

    if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
        BC = exports;
    } else {
        BC = root.BC = {};
    }
    ...
    module.exports = BC;
```

After build I can see in **c:\myapp\platforms\android\assets\www\plugins\org.bcsphere.bluetooth\www\org.bcsphere\bc.js** the whole bc.js file wrapped in

```
cordova.define("org.bcsphere.bluetooth.bcjs", function(require, exports, module) {
...
}
```

I thought now I can do in my **app/js/index.js**

```
onDeviceReady: function() {

    try{
        var BC = window.BC = cordova.require("org.bcsphere.bluetooth.bcjs");
    }
    catch(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
[phonegap] [console.log] module org.bcsphere.bluetooth.bcjs not found
```

Why can't be find the module?